# Formtastic Unable to find input class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

Trying to create a custom input element using Formtastic. Started from something really simple:

`app/input/card_body_input.rb` :

```ruby
class CardBodyInput < FormTastic::Inputs::Base
    include Base

    def input_html_options
      {
        :cols => builder.default_text_area_width,
        :rows => builder.default_text_area_height
      }.merge(super)
    end

    def to_html
      input_wrapping do
        label_html <<
        builder.text_area(method, input_html_options)
      end
    end

  end
```

and I try to use it like this:

```
f.inputs do 
  f.input :back_content as: :card_body
end
```

To which I get `Unable to find input class for card_body`.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: have you tried this https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#modified--custom-inputs

Comment: Yup, that's what I shared above.

Comment: Where is in Rails project placed your file with CardBodyInput class? (requires relative path from root Rails directory)

Comment: app/input - per the instructions in the Formtastic readme.

Comment: and file name of your file is ...?

Comment: app/input/card_body_input.rb - updating question

Comment: The Github page you point (and that's how I have it on my project and it works) that the file should be on `app/inputs` and not `app/input`. Other than that, you code looks good.

Answer (score 1):

You put your file in `app/input`; should be `app/inputs`